# Remove duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Frida - Calling Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53059243/frida-calling-method)

I have no way of getting in touch with Scary Wombat, but he clearly misunderstood or didn't read the question.

The function chall04 works. This question is about hooking methods with frida as I thought was pretty obvious?

What can I do to remove the [duplicate] tag and re-open the question?

Comment: You should really fix the `string2 == "frida"`. That can't be working in Java.

Comment: While it's not well documented - since that user is a gold badge holder and closed your question as a duplicate, they are pingable in comments... Make sure you've got reasoning as to why it's not a duplicate and you can do a comment such as: `@ScaryWombat I don't believe that's a duplicate of what I'm asking because... (explain yourself politely and reasonably here....)` and they'll get notified... (it won't autocomplete but it will work)

Comment: You can ping the close voter in a comment under your question. But if they had problems understanding your question, maybe you need first to work in making it clearer.

Comment: Thanks all. I am trying to explain it better.
@BDL - Perhaps it's bad code, but definitely works - http://swin.es/i/cMWJn.png

Comment: @NanoyMaster: Try `chall04(new String("frida"))` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: @NanoyMaster There is a big difference between code that works and code that works only in very specific situations.

Comment: @BDL No dice with that one, I've also tried instance.challo4.overload('java.lang.String').implementation = function(x){
// call function
}
but no dice.
Don't suppose you want to take this over to the question as it could help others.

Comment: @Gimby Perhaps, but the common denominator is that they work. If it works in a very specific situation then the claim "that can't be working" is, naturally, incorrect.

Comment: @BDL I wouldn't recommend to solve non-meta issues in meta comments: you may instead leave "_try this_" comments on the linked question directly.

Answer (score 8):

> what can I do to remove the [duplicate] tag and re-open the question?

You can't. You can edit your question to clarify, or leave a comment for voters to reconsider. In this case, although I am not overly familiar with Java, it seems like you have a secondary issue in your code when it comes to string comparison.

I would advise listening to the comments people left for you and acting on them. If you still think your question is not a duplicate, you should edit it to clarify.

If your clarification convinces people it's not a duplicate, anyone with more then 3000 reputation can vote to reopen. Five regular reopen voters or one gold tag badge holder will suffice to reopen the question.

Comment: Please note that you have single shot at getting question into re-open queue after an edit. So make sure your first edit is as good as possible.